# R - Check which shift did more hours in which time only using xapply functions

Tags: r, apply

**Data**

```
set.seed(45)
data2 <- data.frame(pora = sample(c("dzień", "noc"), 30, replace=TRUE),
                    ZM1 = sample(1:200, 30, replace=TRUE),
                    ZM2 = sample(1:200, 30, replace=TRUE),
                    ZM3 = sample(1:200, 30, replace=TRUE))
```

[image: Expected output - list with 2 tibbles]

Comment: That's whole output. It's list with 2 elements showing which shift (ZM1 or ZM2) did more hours in given time of day.

Comment: Based on the input showed, i get ZM2 and ZM3 by summing those columns grouped by 'pora'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by 'pora', get the `sum` of 'Z' columns, then reshape from 'wide' to 'long' with `pivot_longer`, `slice` the row where the 'value' column is `max` (`slice_max`), and `split` the 'value' column by 'pora' into a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data2 %>% 
   group_by(pora) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -pora, names_to = 'lepsza') %>% 
   group_by(pora)  %>%
   slice_max(order_by = value, n = 1) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-value) %>%
    {split(.[-1], .$pora)}
```

---

if we want to `*apply` functions

```
lapply(split(data2[-1], data2$pora), function(x) names(x)[which.max(colSums(x))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` you can sum the `ZM.*` columns for each `pora` values. Find the maximum value for each row.

```
tmp <- aggregate(.~pora, data2, sum)
result <- cbind(tmp[1], lepsza = names(tmp)[-1][apply(tmp[-1], 1, which.max)])

#   pora lepsza
#1 dzień    ZM2
#2   noc    ZM3
```

If you want list as output.

```
split(result$lepsza, result$pora)
#$dzień
#[1] "ZM2"

#$noc
#[1] "ZM3"
```